# Add row percentage within top column in proc tabulate (SAS)

Tags: sas, proc

I am using `Proc tabulate` in SAS and I want to make a table like this example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I7JP.png)

As you can see, I want to calculate the `rowpctn` within each year. My problem is that i don't know where to write the `rowpctn` in the code, and after searching the web for an hour, I still haven't been able to find the answer.

My code looks like this:

```
Proc tabulate Data=Have;
class year gender question_1;
table gender, year*question_1;
run;
```

Where do I have to state the rowpctn to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for a response, I kept searching the internet for an answer, and I managed to find a solution myself.

The code is below:

```
Proc tabulate Data=Have;
class year gender question_1;
table gender*pctn<question_1>, year*question_1;
run;
```